# Getting name instead of _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
My schema vicel
  {"_id":"1234st56hk789",
    "name":"aaa",
    "flights":ObjectId(57jhg3455b4h4bnj4g55),
    "org": ObjectId(12345678800rerfgyy)
  }
Flights Schema:
  {"_id":"57jhg3455b4h4bnj4g55",
   "name":"sss",
   "org": ObjectId(12345678800rerfgyy)
  }
```

This my schema, and i group the flights id in vicel model.

My code in controller

```
vicelModel.aggregate([
     "$match":{"org":queryObj.org}
    "$group":{
    _id:"flights",
    total:{$sum: 1}
    }
])
```

In my Advanced Rest i got response like

```
 {meta:
      {status:200
       msg :"ok"
       }
       -response:{
         flights:[2]
          -0: {
               _id:"57jhg3455b4h4bnj4g55"
               total: 3
              }
           -1: {
               _id:"57jhg3455b4h4bn4frg3"
               total: 2
              }
          }
      }
```

but i want name instead of _id  and how to display this total in html page

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample doc?

Answer (score 0):

The $group operator requires that you state every field you want in the output. So when you want the name-field (assuming it is named `name` and in the root of the document), your group object would look like this:

```
"$group":{
    _id:"flights",
    name: "$name",
    total:{$sum: 1}
}
```

Comment: @AntonyMithun What exactly do you mean with "does not work"? It would be a lot easier to help you when you would post an example document.